# Redirect to anchor after form validation

Tags: forms, 6, redirection

I am trying to redirect users to the anchor of the error form field after form validation.

In the form I set the form validation handler with the following code.

```php
$form['#validate'] = 'my_form_validate';
```

In the validation handler, if the form shows some error message, I am trying to scroll to error field.

```php
function my_form_validate() {
    ...
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/' . $form['nid']['#value'] . '#' . $error_field_anchor;
    ...
}
```

The form is not redirecting after validation.

I have tried other paths, such as user/1, node/123 without anchor but the form is not getting redirected to that one.

Comment: Try  `drupal_goto($path);`

Comment: I try function drupal_goto(), and it's work and redirect, but form_validation message not displaying. 
This is one difference between form_state['redirect'] and drupal_goto()
http://drupal.findincity.net/ppst/63547274810018958054256/what-is-the-purpose-and-differences-between-drupalgotodrupalredirectform-and-formstateredirect
this article is answered why drupal_goto() not correct for this case.

Comment: `$form['#validate'] = 'my_form_validate'` replaces any existing validation handler, which may explain why the redirect isn't happening: No validation error is set. This is probably a task to do with JavaScript as what you want to achieve is scrolling the page. Unfortunately, we cannot say why the redirection doesn't take place, since we don't know the code that checks when users should be redirected (which could be wrong code) nor in which hook is the form validation handler added (which could target the wrong form or not form at all).

Answer (score 0):

Use this and put in you form

```
$form_state['redirect'] = 'url';
```

Comment: Nothing changed. After submit wrong form and validation, error message apear and form not redirected.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`drupal_redirect_form($form_state)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7). In the validation function, set the `redirect` element in `$form_state` to the parameters used by [`drupal_goto()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7).

```php
function my_form_validate() {
  // @TODO: Add validation function check
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('node/' . $form['nid']['#value'], array('fragment' => $error_field_anchor));
  drupal_redirect_form($form_state);
}
```

Comment: calling drupal_redirect_form will abort any further form validation. If you are 100% positive that this validate function is the only one that needs to be called, then this is fine. However, if your form may be altered or needs further validation, this approach will break it.

Comment: also, FWIW, doesn't work on Drupal 7